# Issue assigning template class member function pointer to array

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign some member functions to an array of member function pointers. The array is inherited from a template'd base class. This template base class also is used to specify the type of the array. I cannot understand why after init() runs, only element 0 of the array holds the function pointer it was assigned. Element 1 of the array shows all zeros. When I look at the array in memory, it does infact show two elements sequentially, but the sizes in memory seem too big (16 bytes), and my guess is that element 1 is seeing all those zero bytes after the first function pointer as its own value. Why is this happening and what should be done? This code is not my actual project, but I tried to make a minimal example with the same issue.

> main.cpp

```
#include "Statemachine.h" 

int main()
{
    RunnableB myRunnable;
    myRunnable.init();

    return 0;
}
```

> Statemachine.cpp

```
#include "Statemachine.h"

void RunnableB::workFuncOne() 
{
    int j = 7;
    int jPlus1 = j++;
};

void RunnableB::workFuncTwo() 
{
    int a = 8;
    int aPlus1 = a++;
};

void RunnableB::init()
{
    m_workFuncTable[0] = &RunnableB::workFuncOne;
    m_workFuncTable[1] = &RunnableB::workFuncOne;
}
```

> StateMachine.h

```
#pragma once
#include <array>

enum RunnableBEnum
{
    STATE_ONE,
    STATE_TWO,
    STATE_COUNT
};

template <class RunnableType, class EnumType>
class CTtaStateMachine
{
public:

    CTtaStateMachine()
    {
        //m_entryFuncTable.fill(0);
        m_currentState = RunnableBEnum::STATE_ONE;
    }
protected:
    EnumType m_currentState;
    EnumType m_targetState;

    typedef void(RunnableType::*runnableMemberFunc)();

    std::array<runnableMemberFunc, EnumType::STATE_COUNT> m_workFuncTable;


    void executeStateMachine()
    {

        if (0 != m_entryFuncTable[m_currentState])
        {
            (static_cast<RunnableType*>(this)->*m_workFuncTable[m_currentState])();
        }
    }

};

class RunnableB : public CTtaStateMachine<RunnableB, RunnableBEnum>
{
public:

    void init();

private:

    void workFuncOne();

    void workFuncTwo();
};
```

Screenshot of the array variable after init() finishes
[image: Screenshot of the array variable after init() finishes]

Screenshot of the array in memory

[image: Screenshot of the array in memory]

Comment: OT: `init()`? Why don't you use the constructor?

Comment: @manni66 I did have it in the constructor originally, but experienced this issue. So I tried making a separate function as an attempt to resolve it.

Comment: 16 bytes sound okay, pointer to member functions are weird creatures. Does the code actually crash if you call the second pointer, or is it just the debugger being confused?

Comment: Debug or release mode? Set breakpoint at the beginning of both work functions, call them using pointers stored in the array, see if they both get executed.

Comment: @Quentin ah geez It appears it is in fact called. So this is just a visual studio bug..?

Comment: I'd bet on that, because I see nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: I'll second Quentin, the example looks fine. How did you find this bug and how did it manifest in your actual project? If it's really a problem, try assigning the addresses to variables and printing them. You also seem to add function 1 to the array twice. Not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: @Ian In my real project after I implemented this pattern, I wanted to inspect it it in the debugger to verify everything was being set. When it did not appear to be set, I started trying to resolve it, and never actually tried running the program fully. My belief in VS15 was greater than the belief I wasn't doing something wrong. And yes you are right. I realized it after I submitted the question, but I didn't edit it because it didn't impact the problem.

Comment: @JoshD Ok cool, Visual Studio's debugger is not always reliable. Always run the program (if possible) to verify if it's your issue or a VS issue before posting. If it is a VS issue, submit a bug to them.